# Backbone.js rendering Collection View issue

Tags: json, backbone.js, onload

I am an absolute beginner in Backbone.js and I presently have two challenges.

- The first issue concerns the data output from a JSON feed. Some of the data from the JSON feed are not fetch and consequently not displayed. When I inspect the browser network traffic it confirms the browser has not retrieved the entire feed which leaves my app to output default information as defined in the Model.
- The second issue is I don't know how to get the Backbone app to execute on pageload rather than when I enter code into the console area.

My code is below:

```
    <script id='topicTemplate' type='text/template'>
        <td> <%= author %>      </td> 
        <td> <%= weight %>      </td> 
        <td> <%= edit %>        </td>
        <td> <%= nid %>         </td>
        <td> <%= promoted %>    </td>
        <td> <%= status %>      </td>
        <td> <%= title %>       </td>
        <td> <%= content %>     </td>
    </script>

  <!-- =============== -->
  <!-- Javascript code -->
  <!-- =============== -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // your JS code goes here

      //Models
      var TopicStruct = Backbone.Model.extend({
          defaults: {
              author: 'unassigned',
              weight: '',
              edit: '',
              nid: '0',
              promoted: 'n/a',
              status: 'none-existent',
              title: 'Test Topic',
              content: 'none',
          }
      });

      var Topic = Backbone.View.extend({
          tagName: 'tr',
          className: 'topic',
          model: TopicStruct,

          template: _.template( $('#topicTemplate').html() ),

          initialize: function(){
              this.render();
          },

          render: function(){
              this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
          }

      });


      //Collections
      var Topics = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model: TopicStruct,
          url: '/sites/backbone/coordinatorJSON.php',

          render: function(){
              console.log('Topics Render Responding!');
          }
      });

      //views
      var TopicsList = Backbone.View.extend({
          model: 'Topic',
          tagName: 'table',
          className: 'topics',
          initialize: function(){
              console.log('TopicsList:View responding!');
              this.render();
          },
          render: function(){
              //console.log(this);
              this.collection.each( function(topic){

                  eachtopic = new Topic({model:topic});
                  //console.log(eachtopic.el);
                  this.$el.append(eachtopic.el);

                  $('#data').append(this.$el);

              }, this);
          }
      });     

  </script>
```

The JSON data take the following form:

```
[
    {
        "author": "22",
        "weight": "8",
        "edit": "<a href=\"/node/17/edit?destination=sort-coordinator-json\">edit</a>",
        "nid": "17",
        "promoted": "",
        "status": "Active",
        "title": "Social investment tax relief",
        "Content": "<!--form-item-draggableviews--0-->"
    },
    {
        "author": "23",
        "weight": "0",
        "edit": "<a href=\"/node/19/edit?destination=sort-coordinator-json\">edit</a>",
        "nid": "19",
        "promoted": "",
        "status": "Approved",
        "title": "National Insurance: £2,000 employment allowance",
        "Content": "<!--form-item-draggableviews--1-->"
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

The image below shows my output:

[image]

Comment: Where are you initializing your collection and collection view?

Comment: @Jack: In Chrome's console area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your data displayed on `pageload` you need to make sure that whatever *kicks* off your app happens after the `DOM`is loaded. In this case that should be your collections's [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). You also need to make sure your collection is listening to the [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) event and renders it at that point.

For example in your TopicsList view

```
 var TopicsList = Backbone.View.extend({
          tagName: 'table',
          className: 'topics',
          initialize: function(){
              console.log('TopicsList:View responding!');
             // this.render();
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render,this);
          },
```

And then in your DOM ready event

```
$(function() {

 var topics = new Topics();
 var topicsView = new TopicsList({collection: topics});
 topics.fetch({reset: true});
});
```

Here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/duhopupi/2/)

Comment: Thank you Jack. My newbie brain doesn't understand it yet but it worked straight away

Comment: Your welcome, what part are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: Honestly, all of it. I think "this.collection.on ..." is binding a function to the initialize process but I could be wrong. Also, I get an error [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . ] pointing to "var topics.fetch({reset:true});

Comment: `this.collection.on` is binding a function to run when the collection's specified event fires. As for the error, take out the `var`, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: I also updated my jsbin so that it pulls the data using the collection's fetch.